# How to add Font size and Font Family in Ckeditor with react

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor5 with reactJs. I want to provide an option to choose font-size and font-family of their will. But, I have not been able to achieve this feature as of now. I tried this method to add font-size and font family. But, It didn't work.

The other configurations such as blockQuote, Bold, italic etc are working fine. I am not sure where I am making mistake. I also browsed a lot for tutorials for this. Unfortunately, Didn't get any.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
import Formik from "formik";


export default class TextForm extends Component {
    render() {
        
        const sectionName = this.props.sectionName;
        let data = Object.keys(this.props.field).map((elem, index) => {
            return (
                <Container className="mt-3" key={index}>
                    <h3 className="c-subHeading">{this.props.subHeading[index]}</h3>
                    <CKEditor
                        config={{
                            toolbar: [
                                "heading",
                                "|",
                                "fontFamily",
                                "fontSize",
                                "|",
                                "bold",
                                "italic",
                                "link",
                                // "bulletedList",
                                // "numberedList",
                                "|",
                                "blockQuote",
                            ],
                            heading: {
                                options: [
                                    {
                                        model: "paragraph",
                                        title: "Paragraph",
                                        class: "ck-heading_paragraph",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        model: "heading1",
                                        view: "h1",
                                        title: "Heading 1",
                                        class: "ck-heading_heading1",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        model: "heading2",
                                        view: "h2",
                                        title: "Heading 2",
                                        class: "ck-heading_heading2",
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                            fontFamily: {
                                options: [
                                    "default",
                                    "Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif",
                                    "Ubuntu Mono, Courier New, Courier, monospace",
                                ],
                            },
                            fontSize: {
                                options: [9, 11, 13, "default", 17, 19, 21],
                            },
                        }}
                        editor={ClassicEditor}
                        data={this.props.field[elem]}
                        onInit={(editor) => {}}
                        onChange={(event, editor) =>
                            this.props.changeHandler(elem, sectionName, editor.getData())
                        }
                    />
                </Container>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <Form>{data}</Form>
                <button
                    className="c-btn c-btn--right c-btn--medium"
                    onClick={(event) => this.props.updateHandler(event, sectionName)}
                >
                    Update
                </button>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <hr />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have seen the docs as well. But, Not sure where to put that code.

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html

Comment: Pay attantion. You import pre-builded  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic" with limited list of plugins. There are no font plugin. Its very pretty.

Predefined https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/predefined-builds.html#classic-editor

Im continue google how fix ti  ..... (((

Answer (score 0):

i think a plugin is missing. Here ist List of all props https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorconfig-EditorConfig.html

Comment: I have installed the plugin. How am I supposed to integerate it ?

Comment: i hate only providing links, but they are self explanatory :)
[https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html)